# Avoid a form to be opened twice after a button (double) click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm looking for a way to avoid a form to be opened twice. Sometimes it may be possible the user incidentally click the button twice >> the jQuery form is opened twice. **How to avoid this?**

Here is my button:

```
<a class="dialogLink MaterialNew ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-primary" role="button" aria-disabled="false" href="/PLATON/Material/_MaterialEditNew?requestID=10" data-update-url="/PLATON/Material/_MaterialList?requestID=10" data-update-target-id="MaterialList" data-dialog-title="Ajouter un matériel à transporter" data-dialog-id="MaterialNew">
```

This button, when clicked, open a jQuery UI form.

The button has the class .MaterialNew

The form (if exist) has the id #MaterialNew

Thanks for your help.

---

UPDATE

Here is my solution but I'm not quite satisfy with it.

```
// Flag to avoid form to be loaded twice
var formLoaded;

// Wire up the click event of any current or future dialog links
$('.dialogLink').live('click', function () {

    if (formLoaded)
        return false;
    else
        formLoaded = true;
    ....

    $(dialogDiv).load(this.href, function () {
        $(this).dialog({
            modal: true,
            close: function () { $(this).dialog('destroy').remove(); formLoaded = false; },
            ...
```

So as you can see above, I used a flag for checking whether the form is already loaded. I'm not satisfy with this solution, that's my opinion. Maybe a better solution is possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem : form was opening twice in IE after clicking on the button.
Simply adding a "return false;" statement after loading the form did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Just set `disabled` on it when clicked. This will prevent double-clicks, as the second click would hit a disabled control.

Comment: I already try that and the button becomes 'apparently' disabled (I see it as if it is) but I'm still able to click on it and open the jQuery form.

Comment: It may work better if it were an actual `<button>`. Try removing any onClick handlers on the link.

Comment: I updated my question to show my current solution which I'm not satisfy.

Comment: Your current solution works and is perfectly fine as far as I can tell, although you may want to refer to the variable as `window.formLoaded`, rather than relying on an implicit global variable.